# drupal - multiple relationships for views filter

Tags: drupal, filter, view, relationship

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

I have a calendar view with an exposed filter.

I have a parent node and 2 child nodes. Each of these optional child nodes have a common taxonomy term reference field called region.

I would like a single exposed filter which will filter the region selected in either child1 or child2.

I can get it to work for one child node or the other, but am struggling to get it to work with both in one filter.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it's a solution for your problem, but you can try to use **Global: Combine fields filter** (available in Views 3.x). There is a multiple select box, where you can select the fields that you want to filter.